# How to create an account from Smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to create an account from Smack for Android on jabber.at.
Here is my code :

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf= XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                                .setServiceName("jabber.at")
                                .build();
XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf);

connection.addConnectionListener(xmppConnectionListener);
connection.connect();

AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("username", usr);
map.put("password", pwd);
map.put("email", email);
accountManager.createAccount(usr, pwd, map);
```

I got an error:

```
W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.XMPPError@2beba168
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:217)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:198)
```

I have tried with and without the Map, same error.
According to Mathias Ertl from jabber.at, it is possible to create accounts remotely, so I'm doing something wrong somewhere. Any idea ?

Comment: Try Smack 4.1.0-beta2-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but Smack 4.1.0 along with Openfire 3.10.0 does the trick. Thank you.

Comment: If you get the answer you can write answer and mark it correct so that other can be helped. Like I need :)

Answer (score 1):

check if your server support remote account creation.

```
accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()
```

Comment: it returns org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: bad-request - modify