# XMPP register new user

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I am having lots of trouble with XMPP, I am new to it and all the examples that I have found already have an account with which they connect and then do things.

My problem concerns new users. Someone who does not have an account needs to be able to register himself and then log in. But as I have understood, you first need to create a connection before you can create users. So without an account you can not create one.

some links I have been reading:

> http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/platform-ui-home/eclipsecon/tutorial/example2/org.jivesoftware.smack/src/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.java.shtml
>
> https://code.google.com/p/lxmppd/issues/detail?id=328
>
> https://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/
>
> http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/dailybuilds/documentation/connections.html
>
> https://gist.github.com/mindjiver/1605194

So basically, I need to create a connection without user login. Then create a user and login with the user.

So I found this:

> [How to register a new user on XMPP using (a)Smack library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476867/how-to-register-a-new-user-on-xmpp-using-asmack-library)

But it seems that the AccountManager class is outdated or something because I cannot find it in the same path. (http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.0.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html)

**So the question is: How do I create a new account and then login with it(from a new users perspective)?**

A small code snippet or a link to some source would be highly appreciated.

EDIT 1:
I have gotten to this point:

```
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setServiceName("jabber.org")
                .setHost(AppConfig.XMPP_HOST)
                .setPort(Integer.parseInt(AppConfig.XMPP_PORT))
                .build();

        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
```

now I need to instantiate an AccountManager object but its not available in smack 4.1

I am trying to follow this example: [How to create an account from Smack 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221122/how-to-create-an-account-from-smack-4-1)

and even though I read that it should be in smackx. The only thing I can find in smackx is:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.debugger.android.AndroidDebugger
```

Comment: Constructive feedback would be highly apreciated over simply downvoting as I have noticed many people like to do.

Comment: Normally users here like to see an attempt (may be rough) & the specific issue -  along with question.

Comment: @Raúl          Thanks for the feedback, I will post my attempt (the one I am trying right now since I have deleted the older ones)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an account works by first connecting to the server and *then* initializing the account creation. Essentially, you create a connection in which you can create an account, and then proceed to create said account. Here's how I do it:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME)
            .setHost(HOST_NAME)
            .setPort(5222)
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .build();

AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf);
connection.connect(); // Here we create the connection

// Now we create the account:
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
accountManager.createAccount(username, password);

// The account has been created, so we can now login
connection.login(username, password);
```

So we first initialized the connection, created the account, and then logged in. Hopefully this helps

Comment: AccountManager not show in my Android studio, my Account Manager inheritance from androi.accounts, look like my android studio have ambigue import, how i fix this ?

Comment: but it returns org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: bad-request - modify

Answer (score 1):

I have a xmpp service for an Android application. What I have is a Java webserice in the server and a xmpp server. The xmpp server is **OpenFire** which has a plugin for make operation through a http request. This is my web service method where I register new users. I think I end up with this solution because was imposible for me like you to register new users directly from the user. I use asmack in client side too.

```
 public int register(Connection conn,String login,String clave){
    try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            client= WebClientDevWrapper.wrapClient(client);
            //client.setStrictMode(true);
            //client.setTimeout(60000);
            //client.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
            HttpPost post = null;

            String URL="http://your.ip.server:9090/plugins/userService/userservice" +
                    "?type=update&secret="+secret_key_of+"&username="+login.substring(1)+"&password="+clave;
            post = new HttpPost(URL);

            post.setHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

            HttpResponse httpStatus = null;
            int response = 0;
            try {
                httpStatus = client.execute(post);
                response = httpStatus.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
              if(response==200){
                  return 200;
              }else{
                  return 502;
              }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 501;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I might try this method aswell.

Comment: this helped me out cheers! Iam wondering i there a way to register with a set of custom params. for example. the unique id of the device and something like telephone number etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use smack 4.0.6 version. Te latest version (now 4.1.8) doesn't have AccountManager class. My maven dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hmm ill check this when i continue the smack project,, if i continue the smack project. This question is from more than a year ago and by now i have chosen a different implementation for our chat. Maybe in the future i will try out smack again.